# .match is not a function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, match

I have working code in some website. We are changing the design of the website and some functionality so, when i am copy pasting the Jquery. it throws me error. i fixed number of issues, but not able to get what previous developer was trying to do it here:

```
if (dateFormat=='european'){
    dateofbirthString = /^([3][0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])([-])([1][0-2]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])([-])([1][9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][0-1][0-9])$/;
}
if (dateFormat=='american'){    
    dateofbirthString = /^([1][0-2]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])([-])([3][0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])([-])([1][9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][0-1][0-9])$/;
}

if (dob.match(dateofbirthString)){}
```

as per my understanding he was trying to convert it to specific date format selected.

But now i am getting error on **if (dob.match(dateofbirthString)** i.e. **.match is not function**. i have tried the value to convert into string and then used this code, but its output is null.

Please help me what i can use to make it working.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla i have tried this but after that "dob.match(dateofbirthString)" returns NULL

Comment: In this posted code it is very hard to say what is going wrong. If you could mention the specific formats of dob.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
var dob = '11-11-1990';
dateofbirthString.test(dob); // true for america
```

Instead of

```
var dob = '11-11-1990';
dob.match(dateofbirthString) // ["11-11-1990", "11", "-", "11", "-", "1990", index: 0, input: "11-11-1990"]
```

in your code dob should be should be a string. it returns `null` if it is not valid as per the regex (dateofbirthString).. Returns an array as shown above if dob is valid date format

Answer (score -1):

```
 var   dateofbirthString = /^([1][0-2]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])([-])([3][0-1]|[1-2][0-9]|[0][1-9]|[1-9])([-])([1][9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][0-1][0-9])$/;

var dob = "07-14-1995"; //MM-dd-yyyy

console.log(dob.match(dateofbirthString)); 
 // match is found return the result as ["07-14-1995", "07", "-", "14", "-", "1995"] otherwise return null
```